# Save and pass data returned from a promise to functional another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const fetchMusic= () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      const music = musicList.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, 4);
      resolve({ data: music});
    }, 300)
  );
};

export default fetchMusic;


const getRandomMusic = () => {
  return fetchMusic().then((result) => result.data);
};

const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button {...props} onClick={getRandomMusic.bind(this)} />
      <SomeComponent /> 
      <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

musicList is an array of objects having name and year .

const musicList = [{
name: 'abc',
year :1990
},
{
name:'xyz',
year:1989'
}
]

I want to save the data returned from getRandomMusic function and pass it to SomeComponent component.

Comment: Did you tried to add the result to some state variable like : setState({musicList : result.data });? and update the <somecomponent musicList  = {this.state.musicList }>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `useState` ([doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate))

```js
const Button = props => {
  const [musicList, setMusicList] = React.useState([])

  const getRandomMusic = () => {
    fetchMusic().then(result => {
      setMusicList(result.data)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button {...props} onClick={getRandomMusic.bind(this)} />
      <SomeComponent musicList={musicList} />
      <p>Some text here</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```